# Give Virtualbox VM Static IP

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a setup where I have 4 IPs that are statically route to Single IP which is the windows server R2 2012 and this is also the host system.I want to use one of the IPs in ubuntu which is the VM in VirtualBox  . I can ping all ips and can see all ips pointing to same host system .I have tried to use the bridge adapter settings but that didn't work I have asked the help they said that Gw and subnet .Following is the  [screen capture of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRI1X.jpg) in cmd

Comment: Can you try disabling the nic teaming and use just one NIC for the ip's, and again do bridged for the VM.

Comment: I am doing things using RDP if I disable the adapter I will not able to use Host machine

Comment: iLo or iDrac? .. IP KVM, and of course your comment shows you don't have a set-up, you have a managed host somewhere else, so any action you take must be tempered with it potentially taking your access down.  You may not have set-up the bridge adapter for the VM correctly.  Because windows is Teamed, you have to bind to the *team* not the individual network card . see here and then search further. http://pubs.vmware.com/server1/vm/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=vm&file=network_server.8.37.html

Comment: thanks for comment I have confirmed from the host that it's a teamed network and Ips that I want to use are statically routed to 173.x.x.189 and Ips that i want to use is108.x.x.105 ,its subnet is 255.255.255.0 and gateway as the  173.x.x.189 is 173.x.x.185